# Get SCORM values from json in PHP

Tags: php, json, moodle, scorm

The SCORM gives me every time, depending on my progress the following json. I want to import and use it for reporting purposes in my LMS.

```
LMSGetValue("cmi.suspend_data") - {"spoor":{"completion":"----1-1----0---","_isCourseComplete":false,"_isAssessmentPassed":false}} => 0
```

In the completion part, the "1"' (completed) and "0"(not completed) represent the completion progress.

How to represent it in PHP?

Comment: That's not standard SCORM values as suspend_data is purely for the SCO to use as a string of text - (see http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/) - everything in there is part of the SCORM standards anyway - so it would probably help you get an answer if you could say what the platform actually is...?

Comment: It is Moodle 2.7 and the courses are made in Adapt Learning.

Comment: Sounds like something specific to Adept Learning, tried asking on their forums? Though saying that, for the specific questions, ```substr($completion, $index, 1) === "1"``` checks it - but SCORM doesn't  guarantee the order, so you'd need to find out if the order in there is independent of the order of interactions.

Comment: I actually started extracting the characters with something like that:
`foreach(count_chars($data, 1) as $i => $val)`
The only problem now is to find how to get the data from 
cmi.suspend_data.spoor.completion?

Comment: ```$suspend_data = json_decode(LMSGetValue("cmi.suspend_data"));``` - ```$completion = $suspend_data["spoor"]["completion"];```